# validateForInsert fails when I set relationship between two valid objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

I have two models:

```
User
Company
```

User has two attributes:

```
firstName
lastName
```

Company has one attribute:

```
name
```

There is a one to many between User and Company (ie. a user can have multiple companies).

I can create this relationship between the two objects fine in my application. However, I have a unit test that fails when I set up the same relationship like follows:

```
User *user = [UserFactory regularUserInContext:self.context];
Company *comp = [CompanyFactory regularCompanyInContext:self.context];
comp.owner = user;
NSError *error;
XCTAssertTrue([comp validateForInsert:&error], @"Company should save when all properties are set correctly");
```

The Factory methods in question just set the basic attributes on User and Company - I can confirm that these are set correctly. However, the validation step fails due to the following error:

```
Dangling reference to an invalid object
```

It seems that company is complaining that the user object is invalid. However, if I **don't** set the relationship and run `validateForInsert` on the User and Company individually then they successfully pass.

I've also tried setting the relationship on both sides but to no avail. I've set the delete rule on both to be "No action".

My data model is set up such that companies is an optional relationship on User and vice versa. At a loss to figure out why this isn't passing...

Comment: Have you added company to users companySet?

Comment: @NikitaTook I didn't - and you shouldn't have to either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it looks like the issue here had to do with use of different contexts. Previous to this I had Factory classes for both objects that created said objects in a context but, very stupidly, I forgot to initialise the context in question. Since it's a test I decided to use the `MR_createEntity` rather than the `MR_createEntityInContext...` method and this cleared things right up.

Two things about this:

1. It's still pretty odd that validateForInsert doesn't pass as a result of both objects not being attached to a context (or maybe - more likely -  I don't fully understand what exactly is going on here).
2. Xcode error reporting is good as ever `</sarcasm>`